# spread operator on array object does not emit properties

Tags: javascript, redux, ecmascript-6

How do i define an array object with a propery that will be emitted when using a spread operator ,
if such thing is even possible (and why if it is not?) .

I'm using arrays in a redux app so when I'm updating a store with a `return {...state,newElement}` i lose the properties of the arrays in my state .

for example :

```
    const object1 = [1,2,3];

Object.defineProperty(object1, 'pizza', {
  value: 30,
  writable: true,
  enumerable:true,
  configurable:true
});


console.log(...object1);
// output: 1 2 3

// my expected output: 1 2 3 30
```

thanks

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: The spread operator treats arrays as sequences if the context calls for that. You'll need to coerce the array to an object first. `console.log({...object1})`

Comment: "*and why if it is not?*" spreading an iterable only goes through the results of its iterator. So, for an array, that's its values. If you want to have something attached to an array that will show up when spreading, it should be a value. I am really not sure what you're trying to do here if it's not that.

Comment: Also, how are you using spreading with ES5?

Answer (score 0):

The actual iterator of your hybrid object-array is the Array's one (which is  [`Array.prototype.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values)):

```js
const arr = [];

console.log(arr.values === arr[Symbol.iterator])
```

If you want to have an hybrid object-array, and expect it to be fully iterable, you have to write the iterator yourself in order to override the Array's one:

```js
const object1 = [1,2,3];

Object.defineProperty(object1, 'pizza', {
  value: 30,
  writable: true,
  enumerable:true,
  configurable:true
});

object1[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  // Write whatever implementation you need
  for(const key in this) {
    yield this[key];
  }
}


console.log(...object1);
// output: 1 2 3 30
```

Comment: I have a much shorter code that achieves the same. Replace all but the first and the last line with `object1.push(30)`. I don't really see the value of reinventing this piece of code.